# How to allow ecs private application access to internet if using only aws PrivateLink

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, vpc, amazon-ecr

I have deployed multiple applications(docker containers) by ECS on private subnet. NAT Gateway is used to allow internet access. Due to active deployment, the images download from ECR by nat gateway is costing too much due to their size.

I am planning on using AWS PrivateLink. But will AWS PrivateLink allow access to internet from my apps or can I use PrivateLink only for ECR image downloads from ECR and natgateway for occasional internet connectivity for my applications.

Thanks for your Valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the internet outside of AWS services in a private instance if you're only using AWS PrivateLink.

You can download ECR images through VPC endpoints instead of a NAT gateway. The following endpoints are required:

```
com.amazonaws.region.ecr.dkr 
com.amazonaws.region.ecr.api
com.amazonaws.region.ecr.s3
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html